# Approximating $(\log n)^n$ using Big O notation

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, asymptotics, approximation

As stated in the title I am trying to find a good approximation in O notation for:
$$(\log n)^n = \log (n) \cdot \log (n) \cdot ... \cdot  \log (n)$$.
I have tried using L'Hôpital's rule for the term
$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(\log n)^n}{2^n}$
to get a starting point. But I don't think that it helps much in this case as the derivative of $(\log n)^n$ is something along the lines of $\ln^x\left(x\right)\left(\ln\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)+\dfrac{1}{\ln\left(x\right)}\right)$ and does not really simplify the term.

(How can we get a good approximation for the term?)

EDIT:
Is there a closer bound than the trivial $(\log n)^n \in O(n^n)$. And if there is how do we prove that?
EDIT2:
Closest lower bound I have found is:
$(\log n)^n \in \Omega(a^n)$ where $a \in \mathbb{N}^+$. Since $ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(\log n)^n}{a^n} = \lim_{x\to \infty} (\frac{\log n}{a})^n = \infty$, $\log n$ is bigger and therefore $(\log n)^n \in \Omega(a^n)$.

Comment: I think it should be obvious but $\log^n{n} = n^{n\log_n(\log(n))} = n^{n\frac{\log{\log{n}}}{\log{n}}}$ using exponent laws. I don't see why you'd need a bound when this is the *exact* form. If you find it messy writing the logs in the exponent you could also write $n^{o(n)}$ which still beats $n^n$

Comment: Ok, thanks.. But I am looking for a bound in a more simple form..
For example the lower bound i have proven in EDIT2 of my question is quite obvious. As is the upper bound of $n^n$. But is $n!$ an upper bound of the function in question? If so, what does the proof look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this as an answer as it's too large to fit into a comment. The $n!$ bound follows from [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) which states

$$\log(n!) = n\log{n}-n+O(\log{n}).$$

As I said in the comment $(\log{n})^n = n^{n\frac{\log\log{n}}{\log{n}}}$, and using Stirling's formula gives

$$n! = n^{\frac{log(n!)}{\log{n}}} = n^{\frac{1}{\log{n}}(n\log{n}-n+O(\log{n}))} = n^{n\left(1-\frac{1}{\log{n}} + O(1/n)\right)}.$$

Looking at the exponents, you can see that $n!$ is larger, but the exponent is still asymptotic to $n$ which is why I think $(\log{n})^n = n^{o(n)}$ is better, since $\frac{\log\log{n}}{\log{n}}$ approaches zero as $n\to\infty$. Also, this translates to an upper bound of the form $n^{\epsilon\cdot n}$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, which beats $n!$ for any $\epsilon \lt 1$.